# How to put divs side by side?

Tags: html, css

So I am having trouble putting two divs `side` and `map` to be next to each other. I currently have:

**CSS**

```
.col-md-8 { float: right; clear: right;}
.col-md-4 { float: left; clear: left; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div style="width: 700px;" class='col-md-4' id="side">
        </div>

        <div class='col-md-8' id="try">
            <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I would like the divs `#side` and `#map` to be next to each other... so in that case wouldn't I put `#side` and `#try` side by side?  So I tried that with the CSS, with `float: right` and `float: left`? I just can't figure out whats wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: you have side and try as id's and are calling them classes in the css. if you want to keep them as id's you need to change it to `#try` and `#side` in the css.

Comment: Have you tried making them both float left? Don't forget to clear your floats after.

Comment: @ajmajmajma Thanks! Silly newbie mistake... so that would be the right way to do it, correct?

Comment: you are using bootstrap concept here. Check if you have correctly referenced bootstrap main css in the page head.

Comment: I believe bootstrap has built in ways of doing this, check out their documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up several different style attributes.

You have defined [CSS classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), but are trying to use them to target an [Element Id attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes).

```
.try { float: right;}
.side { float: left; }
```

You can change your CSS to target the element Id instead.

```
#try { float: right;}
#side { float: left; }
```

You are also using using bootstrap classes and have specifically chosen one for a responsive layout (using the `container-fluid` class). By defining a `div` as a `row` and giving the elements in that div column classes, they will float appropriately, based on the total of 12 columns.

Finally, you contradict the bootstrap classes by then setting explicit widths on your divs.  You can have 1 or the other.  You **should not** do both.

Until you decide on using bootstrap OR using hard coded widths, it will not layout correctly.

Comment: Ohhh I see thank you. So by default bootstrap basically splits my page in half, and because I was hardcoding my widths, it was interfering with bootstrap and had to stack instead.

Comment: Bootstrap uses 12 columns.  Your first div you set 4 columns wide.  Your second div you set to 8 columns wide.  That's 12 (or less).  They will set side by side on the page.

Comment: I see, thank you for clearing up my confusion! I obviously had a major conceptual understanding issue, and you cleared it up :)

Answer (score 2):

In your example you put `#map` inside the `#try`-div, therefore it is not possible to float them next to each other.

Your Code could look like this:

```css
#side,
#map {
  float: left;
  background: green;
  border: 10px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>

    <div>

        <div id="side">
        </div>

        <div id="try">
            <div id="map">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I removed the style-attribute on the #map and added background, border, width and height only to show you that it works.

For the use of bootstrap-classes look at whipdancers answer!

Comment: You are still mixing bootstrap responsive classes with hard coded widths.

Comment: That's correct, i didn't look at these classes, when I postet the answer. I will edit it now!

Comment: @user6149228 Thank you so much for the example!

Answer (score 1):

First issue is that you are fighting the grid. The two divs will automatically display inline block so long as you don't exceed the width of the container (which you are in this case - I see you are using bootstrap). If you do exceed this width, they will stack instead.

That said - if you take breaking the grid out of the equation (dont put fixed widths on responsive columns) - to place divs side by side use:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class = "one"></div>
    <div class = "two"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You are welcome. Honestly, if you just remove the fixed width and use the columns to set your width, you wont have to float the divs. As long as the columns per row is 12 (or less) - the divs in them will always float next to one another unless you hit a mobile breakpoint. Also, remember - columns can be nested.